# optimize Insert query with minus oracle

Tags: oracle, performance, query-optimization

Wanted to optimize an important statement that is taking longer to finish.

Basically the process will:

1) insert data on NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP by 5 inserts, one by one. These DMLs uses to take 10 seconds per query. From the last trace, these DMLs inserted the below count of rows:

```
Insert 1 - 292770
Insert 2 - 106648
Insert 3 - 67358
Insert 4 - 47775
Insert 5 - 6147
```

2) Problematic query run, inserting around 6 rows only on table NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY (this table has around 414k rows).

```
INSERT INTO NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY(ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,ADDED_DATE)
    SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,:B1 AS ADDED_DATE 
    FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP 
    WHERE (ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE) IN (
            SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE 
            FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP
            MINUS 
            SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE 
            FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY );
```

3) Process delete data from NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY table. It's fine as well.

```
DELETE FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY
WHERE
 (ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE) IN ( SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE
  FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY MINUS SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE
  FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP );
```

Below is the trace for the problematic insert:

```
SQL ID: gwxs083gcfdd2 Plan Hash: 2436575860

INSERT INTO NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY(ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,ADDED_DATE)
   SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,:B1 AS ADDED_DATE FROM
  NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP WHERE (ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE) IN (
  SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP
  MINUS SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY )



call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Execute      1   6704.07    6705.98          2  424814954         25           6
Fetch        0      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total        2   6704.07    6705.98          2  424814954         25           6

Misses in library cache during parse: 1
Misses in library cache during execute: 1
Optimizer mode: ALL_ROWS
Parsing user id: 146     (recursive depth: 1)
Number of plan statistics captured: 1

Rows (1st) Rows (avg) Rows (max)  Row Source Operation
---------- ---------- ----------  ---------------------------------------------------
         0          0          0  LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL  (cr=424814954 pr=2 pw=0 time=923492126 us)
         6          6          6   FILTER  (cr=424814953 pr=0 pw=0 time=1667461141 us)
    414050     414050     414050    TABLE ACCESS FULL NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP (cr=1023 pr=0 pw=0 time=121231 us cost=2 size=35 card=1)
         6          6          6    MINUS  (cr=424813930 pr=0 pw=0 time=2409881660 us)
    414050     414050     414050     SORT UNIQUE NOSORT (cr=423573150 pr=0 pw=0 time=2406932080 us cost=3 size=35 card=1)
    414050     414050     414050      TABLE ACCESS FULL NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP (cr=423573150 pr=0 pw=0 time=2406112290 us cost=2 size=35 card=1)
    414044     414044     414044     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN NG_ORG_CATEGORY_PK (cr=1240780 pr=0 pw=0 time=2134347 us cost=2 size=11 card=1)(object id 108100)


Elapsed times include waiting on following events:
  Event waited on                             Times   Max. Wait  Total Waited
  ----------------------------------------   Waited  ----------  ------------
  gc cr grant 2-way                               1        0.00          0.00
  db file sequential read                         2        0.13          0.13
  gc current grant 2-way                          6        0.00          0.00
********************************************************************************
```

Could you please help me and let me know how can I tuning this query? I was thinking in add a parallel hint, but it will be ignored due to the MINUS on the query.

Please let me know if you have any idea and if you need any other information.

Appreciate your attention on it.

Thanks in advance,

Will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use an inner join  instead of a where  (   ) IN

```
INSERT INTO NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY(ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,ADDED_DATE)
SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,:B1  
FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE 
    FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP
    MINUS 
    SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE 
    FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY 
) T1 on NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP.ORGANIZATION_ID =  T1.ORGANIZATION_ID 
          and NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP.CATEGORY_CODE = T1.CATEGORY_CODE
```

and a simple tips  remove the alias form select  (are not useful )

Comment: Hi @scaisEdge... I worked and ran in less than 1 sec! I just need to confirm the data, but I ran a count MINUS before the insert and it inserted the same count of data. I will check with developers on Monday and get back to this post! For now, THANKS A LOT, you are the MAN!

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, you want to insert data into gtmp table only if it doesn't exist in category table.
you can try the below query:

```
  INSERT INTO NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY(ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,ADDED_DATE)
     SELECT ORGANIZATION_ID,CATEGORY_CODE,:B1 AS ADDED_DATE FROM
    NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY_GTMP T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM NG_ORGANIZATION_CATEGORY T2 WHERE  T1.ORGANIZATION_ID=T2.ORGANIZATION_ID AND T1.CATEGORY_CODE=T2.CATEGORY_CODE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a MERGE statement to populate the target table with only the rows from the source table which don't exist:

```
merge into ng_organization_category noc
using ( select distinct organization_id,
               category_code
        from ng_organization_category_gtmp ) gtmp
  on ( gtmp.organization_id =  noc.organization_id 
       and gtmp.category_code = noc.category_code )
when not matched then
    insert (organization_id, category_code, added_date)
    values (gtmp.organization_id, gtmp.category_code, :B1)
/
```

The DISTINCT in the USING sub-query may not be necessary, it depends on your source data. (Your existing INSERT statement would insert multiple instances of `(organization_id, category_code)` if the GTMP table has them, so may it doesn't matter.)

Comment: Hi @APC.. thanks for your help! I will wait until the DEV validate the suggestion provided by scaisEdge, if it is not useful.. I will try your indication! Really appreciate your help.